# Manually Encode a Password in php symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I want to Manually Encode a Password (login password not api hash)
in Symfony

here is the security config:

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        login:
            pattern:  ^/auth-api/login
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            json_login:
                check_path:               /auth-api/login_check
                success_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure

        api:
            pattern:   ^/auth-api
            stateless: true
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            user_checker: security.user_checker
            form_login:
                default_target_path: /accounts
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager

            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

            # activate different ways to authenticate
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#firewalls-authentication

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
            # switch_user: true

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
        # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/api/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/api,       roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

i try this code in APiController.php

```
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Repository\AccountsRepository;
use InstagramAPI\Instagram;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
.....
$encoder = $this->get('security.encoder_factory')->getEncoder($userClass);
$encodedPassword = $encoder->encodePassword("test");
   echo $encoded;
```

got this error

> Service "security.encoder_factory" not found: even though it exists in the app's container, the container inside "App\Controller\APiController" is a smaller service locator that only knows about the "doctrine", "form.factory", "http_kernel", "parameter_bag", "request_stack", "router", "security.authorization_checker", "security.csrf.token_manager", "security.token_storage", "serializer", "session", "templating" and "twig" services. Try using dependency injection instead.

i also try this code:

```
....
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User;
...
   $user = new App\Entity\User();
    $plainPassword = 'ryanpass';
    $encoded = $encoder->encodePassword($user, $plainPassword);

    $user->setPassword($encoded);
```

got this error:

> Cannot use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as User because the name is already in use

Comment: The given code is not complete. Additionally, why not use autowiring for this?

Answer (score 0):

As it mentioned, use dependency injection https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html

For controller, you can bind a service via `__constructor` or as an `argument` of an action

use the console cmd to find its type hint
`bin/console debug:autowiring encoder_factory`